# Unable to find conflict from the error message "Could not resolve"

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using gradle build system and trying to upgrade to ES7 from 5.6. My base package's (lets call it `core`) build.gradle has the ES dependencies

```
    api ('org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.12.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', module: 'jackson-module'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-databind'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-annotations'
    }
    api 'org.elasticsearch.client:transport:7.12.1'
    api 'org.elasticsearch.plugin:transport-netty4-client:7.12.1'
    api ('org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:4.2.1') {
        //exclude group: 'org.elasticsearch', module: 'elasticsearch'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', module: 'jackson-module'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-databind'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-annotations'
    }
```

The module which depends on it has build.gradle

```
api project(':core')
```

While building the code I get the error

```
> Could not resolve org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.12.1.
     Required by:
         project :httpquinn
      > Could not resolve org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.12.1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://maven-internal:8080/repository/internal/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.12.1/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.12.1.module'.
            > Could not GET 'http://maven-internal:8080/repository/internal/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.12.1/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.12.1.module'. Received status code 500 from server: Unable to fetch artifact resource.
   > Could not resolve org.elasticsearch.client:transport:7.12.1.
     Required by:
         project :httpquinn
      > Could not resolve org.elasticsearch.client:transport:7.12.1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://maven-internal:8080/repository/internal/org/elasticsearch/client/transport/7.12.1/transport-7.12.1.module'.
            > Could not GET 'http://maven-internal:8080/repository/internal/org/elasticsearch/client/transport/7.12.1/transport-7.12.1.module'. Received status code 500 from server: Unable to fetch artifact resource.
```

I tried restricting the versions using `strictly`

```
    api ('org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.12.1') {
        version {
            strictly '7.12.1'
        }
    }

    api ('org.elasticsearch.client:transport:7.12.1') {
        version {
            strictly '7.12.1'
        }
    }
```

I am not able to identify from where the conflict is arising.

Comment: Turns out the resource wasn't available on the internal repo and was unable to pull from the external one. We fixed the hierarchy of pulling libraries.